# How do I return an array of objects with certain conditions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object called shows:

```
const shows =  [{
   "name": "John Doe Show",
   "rating": 1234,
   "alternative_name": null,
},
{
   "name": "Jane Doe Show",
   "rating": 4321,
   "alternative_name": "Alternate Name 2",
}
{
   "name": "Other Show",
   "rating": 8842,
   "alternative_name": "Alternate Name 3",
}];
```

I specifically want to get the alternative_name in a function getAlternateName(). But I want the condition for it to be that it should not be null. How would I go about it?

Edit: For example, for the Jane Doe Show, it has an alternative_name with "Alternate Name 2," while for the John Doe Show, alternative_name is null. When I console.log(getAlternateName()), it would show:

```
[ { alternative_name: null },
{ alternative_name: 'Alternate Name 2' },
{ alternative_name: 'Alternate Name 3' } ]
```

However, I just want it to show "Alternate Name 2 and Alternate Name 3, without showing null. How would I go about it?

Comment: can you write more detail about your question,  `shows` is an array now.

Comment: Filtered based on which property? And what result that you expect when the "alternative_name" is null?

Comment: For example, for the Jane Doe Show, it has an alternative_name with "Alternate Name 2," while for the John Doe Show, alternative_name is null. When I console.log(getAlternateName()), it would show both alternative_name, however, I just want it to show the alternative_name for the Jane Doe Show

Comment: then, you expect to filter them by "alternative_name" only? so, data without "alternative_name" will not be shown?

Comment: Yes, I only want data for "alternative_name." I don't want null to be shown with the other data when I console.log the function.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58813889/4147978), there's I've created two methods as you expect

Comment: Welcome to SO :) This is a two-liner if done right, [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58814250/199263)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** [There is a better solution by ***AndreasPizsa***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813559/how-do-i-return-an-array-of-objects-with-certain-conditions-in-javascript/58814250#58814250).

Here is a function that will return an array of all the alternative names in the array `shows`. If there is no alternative name in the array, it will not appear in the returned array.

```
function getAlternateName() {
    this.alternateNames = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < shows.length; i++) {
        if (shows[i].alternative_name) {
            this.alternateNames.push(shows[i].alternative_name);
        }
    }
    return this.alternateNames;
}
```

```js
const shows = [{
    "name": "John Doe Show",
    "rating": 1234,
    "alternative_name": null,
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane Doe Show",
    "rating": 4321,
    "alternative_name": "Alternate Name 2",
  },
  {
    "name": "Bill Doe Show",
    "rating": 1243,
    "alternative_name": "Alternate Name 3",
  },
  {
    "name": "Jill Doe Show",
    "rating": 4312,
    "alternative_name": null,
  }
];

function getAlternateName() {
  this.alternateNames = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < shows.length; i++) {
    if (shows[i].alternative_name) {
      this.alternateNames.push(shows[i].alternative_name);
    }
  }
  return this.alternateNames;
}

console.log(getAlternateName());
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the `alternative_name` with `map`, then `filter` for nun-`null` values. I took the liberty to just return an array of strings, not objects, to keep the result short & focused.

```js
const shows =  [{
   "name": "John Doe Show",
   "rating": 1234,
   "alternative_name": null,
},
{
   "name": "Jane Doe Show",
   "rating": 4321,
   "alternative_name": "Alternate Name 2",
},
{
   "name": "Other Show",
   "rating": 8842,
   "alternative_name": "Alternate Name 3",
}];

const alternativeNames = shows
    .map(({alternative_name}) => alternative_name)
    .filter(x => x)
    
console.log(alternativeNames)
```

Comment: waldo233, this is the best solution for your problem ;)

Comment: This is better than my solution, use it instead!

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods:

```js
const shows =  [{
   "name": "John Doe Show",
   "rating": 1234,
   "alternative_name": null,
},
{
   "name": "Jane Doe Show",
   "rating": 4321,
   "alternative_name": "Alternate Name 2",
},
{
   "name": "Other Show",
   "rating": 8842,
   "alternative_name": "Alternate Name 3",
}];

function getAltName(oName) {
  const result = shows.filter(x => x.name === oName)[0];
  return result.alternative_name || "Can not find your expected data.";
}

// this method to trims and take only data with alternative_name.
function trimByAltName() {
  return shows.filter(x => x.alternative_name !== null);
}

console.log('Get alternative name only:', getAltName('Jane Doe Show'));

console.log('Get Filtered Data:', trimByAltName());
```